# Vertical ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Has anybody managed to implement a vertical ViewPager by trying to change the source code of [ViewPager](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/compatibility/AndroidSupportV2/src/android/support/v2/view/ViewPager.java?r=3488)?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to make it work ? if  yes, could u provide the code. thanks a lot.

Comment: Yep. Give me your e-mail and I'll send it to you. It's not perfect though.

Comment: Could you also send it to me, please? I will help me so much. thedistortion [at] yandex [dot] ru

Comment: I'd love to have it as well, if you dont mind.. rlp at nebular.tv

Comment: any chance that you can post the code ? here or at Github ?

Comment: Hey, can you try this solution? [Vertical ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager/18657771#18657771)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to edit the source code for ViewPager and swap out all x,y and width,height logic. DirectionalViewPager should do the job. Here is the source: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager

Comment: I don't need the swap from horizontal to vertical function that Jake's Pager has. I just need a ViewPager that scrolls vertically. I guess nobody's done, huh. What I'm really doing is trying to find a way not to do all that work. :)

Comment: Why not look at the source for DirectionalViewPager and see how it has been implemented there, and write your own that doesn't include all the extra stuff you don't need?