# How to implement a swipe-gesture between Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

I would like to implement in my android app that I'm developing with the Android studio ide.
The swipe between the different tabs (fragment). I tried searching online and on StackOverflow but I could not quite understand.
My action bar is the classic one that works with Android above 3.0
If you can give me some advice or examples of aid etc. I shall be very grateful.
With this I thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suppose the **Android ViewPager** is what you are looking for:

**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html**

Here is a nice **tutorial** on how to implement it:

**http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html**

> The basic idea is that you have **multiple Fragments, each representing
>   a different Screen.** The ViewPager enables the user to swipe between
>   the different Fragments and display different content.

Also take a look at this question:

[How to implement a ViewPager with different Fragments / Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts/18413437#18413437)

And how to include the Support-Library: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Please take a look at the question link I posted. There I explain in detail how the ViewPager works.

Comment: I know, but i didn't use ListFragment Or FragmentActivity for main_activity

Comment: That doesn't matter. You do not need to use a ListFragment. Just use whatever Fragment you want, just make sure its a support.v4.Fragment.

Comment: Concerning the FragmentActivity: Can't you just let your Activity extend FragmentActivity?

Comment: I checked in support.v4.Fragment "Fragment" doesn't find

Comment: That is probably because you do not have the Support-Libary included in your project: Here is how to do that: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36725/discussion-between-lillogoal-and-philipp-jahoda)

Comment: i'm testing
i use this example developer.android.com/…
i use action bar with table listener with android.support.v4.Fragment i got an error
i follow tutorial and swipe work, but i want to show l'action bar