# How to implement a horizontal scroll / swipe between Fragments?

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, scroll, swipe-gesture

I would like to achieve a navigation in my app like Pinterest or Trello, that is, kind of three tabs to navigation + horizontal scrolling.
I have made a custom tabbar for this (since I couldn't guess how to change tabs width in my actionbar with navigation TAB mode). So I have three buttons to navigate from one fragment to another. Now I would like to implement the horizontal scrolling like these two examples, to also navigate among my fragments.
I have read about View Pager but I don't know if it fits to my case, since I don't have only views but fragments. Does anybody have an example or an idea of how to do it? Could I apply it among different activities?
Thanks

Comment: How about implementing [effective navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at the duplicate question that I just answered:

**[How to implement a swipe-gesture between Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591265/how-to-implement-a-swipe-gesture-between-fragments/18591363#18591363)**

I suppose the **Android ViewPager** is what you are looking for:

**http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html**

Here is a nice **tutorial** on how to implement it:

**http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html**

> The basic idea is that you have **multiple Fragments, each representing
>   a different Screen.** The ViewPager enables the user to swipe between
>   the different Fragments and display different content.

Comment: Thasnks, that is what I was seeing in my searching. But it will be compatible with my customTab Navigation? This is not a current actionBar with Tabs, but a custom actionbar with three buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager. More information about viewpager [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: I don't know how to mix both NavigationTab and ViewPager. I tried to add ViewPager and it works (although I don't know how to start in the middle position), but if I try to use Tabs it cracks.