# Horizontal swipe between two separated layouts

Tags: android, layout, swipe, horizontal-scrolling

I need to swipe between my two almost identic but separated layouts. Like just swipe screen by fingertip and the picture will change and some text will change too... thats all. :) But, isn't there a problem, when I'm using RelativeLayout at both of them?

Comment: Use view pager for sliding purpose . http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: probable duplicate question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594482/how-to-implement-a-horizontal-scroll-swipe-between-fragments

Answer (score 0):

**Spartacus Hello**

Bro use pager view for horizontal swipe, here is a simple exapmle of pager view:-

[Check it out:-](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

If you found any issue regarding this please let me know i love to help you,

Spartacus Thanks:- :)