# how to implement swipe feature like gmail in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, swipe

[response is coming in form of json format. With the help of volley lib i am fetching the response and showing it in a recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgEAb.jpg)

[onClickItem i am able to show response in another activity.**i have completed till this step**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKjtx.jpg)

[i want the swipe functionality jus like gmail in my app . but i am unable to do it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C89Ka.jpg)

Can someone please help me how should i do this ? i am new to android .
i searched everything on the web ,but i didn found anything .

is this feature possible with recycler view (if yes then please suggest how should i do this )? or do i need to use any other components ?

Thanks in adv. :)

Comment: check it - https://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-creating-gmail-like-inbox-using-recyclerview/

Comment: Thnx for ua reply @AD 10.. That is pretty cool.. But I don't want just the animation on the recycler view activity..I want to show a complete particular message in another activity, with swipe left feature to see other emails..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594482/how-to-implement-a-horizontal-scroll-swipe-between-fragments

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `Layout Inspector` on the screen, it seems to be implemented using ViewPager.

[image]

Comment: Thnx @pistolcaffe ..do you have any links o tutorials in which I can follow steps to achieve this functionality?

Comment: @NehankPoilkar please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide