# Android ViewPager with Fragments getting Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a simple ViewPager with two fragments. I am Using two fragments and adding them to a viewPager to test the simple ViewPager. But i am getting error. Please help me

Main Class is:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
ViewPager viewpager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter=new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return fragments.size();
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return fragments.get(position);
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //return new AboutUs();
            return new Programs();
        case 1:
            return new fragment2Activity();
        }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

}

FirstFragment is:

```
public class fragment2Activity extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPause();
    onDestroyView();
}
private String mContent = "???";
private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ((savedInstanceState != null)
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
        mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
    }

    }
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout, container, true);

}
```

}

SecondFragment is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Programs extends Fragment 
{

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onDestroy();
}

private String mContent = "???";
private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPause();
    onDestroyView();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ((savedInstanceState != null)
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
        mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
    }

    }
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
    return inf;
}
```

}

I am getting the followinf Error:

```
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child     already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3345)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3216)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3173)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3153)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2162)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1091)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2505)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-27 10:54:05.157: E/AndroidRuntime(21364):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , add this in `MainActivity`

```
Vector<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Programs.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, fragment2Activity.class.getName()));
    adapter=new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
```

And make changes in `MyPagerAdapter`

```
 private List<Fragment> fragments;
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return this.fragments.get(position);

    }
```

and remove `isViewFromObject()` .

Comment: thnx..it worked...can you please explain a bit what was the mistake i was doing :)

Answer (score 1):

a couple things:

1. in your adapter, do this instead:

   ```
   @Override

   public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {

     return **arg0==arg1**;

   }
   ```
2. in your `onCreateView`s, do this instead:

   ```
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout, container, **false**);
   ```
3. if it still doesn't work, try overriding destroyItem() in the adapter:

   ```
   @Override

   public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

     ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);

   }
   ```

Comment: thnankx.. error gone..but i cant see any thing on the screen..i am gettign blank screen..
this is my activity_main.xml layout.
    
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview" />

Comment: weird... can you check first to make sure that your fragments show up ok on a normal non-pager screen?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link where you get simple example with proper layouts.
[How to implement a ViewPager with different Fragments / Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)