# How to implement FragmentPager inside Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have project:

Activity with 2 dynamically added fragments

Fragment#1 
that is a list of objects (using listView and adapter), when user click on list item here comes Fragment#2

Fragment#2
that is a description of an object. Here i want to use FragmentPager to simple change objects

I have tried to use [that solution](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/) but in my opinion I have to use it in fragment (not in Activity as example shows)... or in adapter?? i don't know...

How Can I do that?

Comment: Please, Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18413437/3330969).

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested

Comment: ok i have used example of @Sreekanthss and I have FragmentPager now but when I press back I have list again and then if I press again on any Item I have empty page... previous fragment replace commit works fine but now commit gives nothing... (no error, no worning, just blank page)

Comment: ok I have an answer PageAdapter should extend 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter' now everything works fine :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy one, Simply you've to convert that `FragmentActivity` of the `ViewPager` to `Fragment`
using the following way

Make your class extend `Fragment` not `FragmentActivity` in which you want to use `ViewPager`

then create the following methods to work with *Fragmets* using `ViewPager`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_reminder_main, container,
                false);

        view_pager = (ViewPager) view
                .findViewById(R.id.child_main_pager);
        return view;
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onActivityCreated(arg0);

            view_pager.setAdapter(new CustomFragmetPagerAdapter(
                    getChildFragmentManager()));
    }
```

keep the following in field level

```
private ViewPager view_reminder_pager;
```

I hope this would help you :)