# Viewpager inside a fragment is it possible

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I want to know whether its possible to create a following UI in android.

I am having a `navigation drawer`. It calls `fragment` A as the main UI. In `fragment` A i want to use `viewpager` to display different `tabs`.

Comment: Yes It is possible, Have a look at to this very easy [example answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18413437/3330969)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just implement the Sliding Menu Library, and when you click a Menu Item from the Sliding Menu, start an FragmentSlidingActivity(Fragment Activity extends SlidingMenu's FragmentActivity to be able to slide) which has Tabs with Fragments inside.

And if you are looking for different back stack for each tab under Tab Host (like it is used to be with TabActivity which is deprecated ), you can take a look on my example project on [GitHub](https://github.com/osayilgan/samples).

[Here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) is the link to the Sliding Menu Library.

See as suggested: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

or this for a quick tutorial: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html