# having troubles with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I've searched allot, and after more in depth and reading, I got the ViewPager to work using this answer - [How to implement a ViewPager with different Fragments / Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts/18413437#18413437) But now I cannot link it to my existing layouts.

I already used MainActivity and it has code that displays the time and stuff so I just made the ViewPager activity called Launch activity but within it, you an set the pages to scroll to, like this -

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    switch(pos) {

    case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
    case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
    case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
    case 3: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 2");
    case 4: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
    default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
    }
}
```

But when I change FirstFragment or any of the return states to my pre made classes, it doesn't work. Is there anything I have to do to get it to work?

Explained, furthermore.

So I have my application already set up, but I wish to have it better laid out and more organised, instead of having to scroll a billion times. So I would like to link to my ViewPager to all my activities so I can swipe amongst them. But the problem comes upon adding the class (Activity) to the fragments section (Code above). I simply cannot add it to the section. when I do it gives me an error and tells me this - The method newInstance(String) is undefined for the type MainActivity. so I clicked create method, but I dont know what to do in there, all I want to do is simply link my class that contains functions to my viewpager.

Comment: Your question and explanations are not very clear. Could you please improve them?

Comment: show the code you are talking about. It sounds like you are trying to add an activity to your viewpager, but its supposed to only hold fragments, not activities,

Comment: @DanielBo You are correct, I just found out that viewpager only works with fragments, so how am I supposed to get viewpager to work?

Comment: you could just move your code from an activity into a fragment?

Comment: That didn't work, I ended up converting the Activity into a fragment then used getView and getActivity to fix some errors.