# ViewPager in android Null pointer exception

Tags: android

ViewPager gives null pointer exception.

**I am trying to add tab and view pager inside fragment**

Below is my code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle       
savedInstanceState)    
{
mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.activity_main_fragment_layout);
mViewPager = (ViewPager) mTabHost.findViewById(R.id.tabHostWithViewPager);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Fragment B"), FragmentB.class,
null);
}
FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new    
FragmentPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(arg0);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
            // actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
        }

    });
    return mTabHost;
}
```

activity_main_fragment_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/tabHostWithViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>

FragmentPagerAdapter.java

 public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return new FragmentA();
}
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.I can add tab in fragment but gets null pointer exception when trying to implement viewpager.Viewpager gives null pointer exception
[image]

Please find out the logcat

Comment: Post `fragmentPagerAdapter` code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts and http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/10/viewpager-example-in-android.html

Comment: @bipin I have posted ViewPagerAdapter code..I using fragment not activity

Comment: @DevCarlsberg I have posted Logcat.Please help me

Comment: @shayanpourvatan
in this line mViewPager = (ViewPager) mTabHost.findViewById(R.id.tabHostWithViewPager);
mViewPager is null

Comment: so `mTabHost` is null