# Activity with Multiple Animated Fragments

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I currently have one Activity which contains a `Fragment` by injecting it inside a `LinearLayout` during runtime.

Inside my `Activity` layout, I have a `Button` view called `nextButton`. When I click this button, I want the `Activity` to switch to the next `Fragment` but ALSO animate where the current fragment moves off the screen to the left and the new fragment comes in from the right. As if the new fragment is pushing the current fragment out of the way.

Below is a demonstration of what I want.

[image]

Shall I store all of the Fragments in an `ArrayList<Fragment>` and just inject the current index + 1 in to the `LinearLayout` when the `nextButton` is clicked? What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is ViewPager, [See one good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)

You need to do selectPage with in your nextButton, here **true** is for smooth scroll animation.

```
pager.setCurrentItem( num,true )
```

[Please find Reference link here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 4 animation for entering (left and right) and exiting animation (left and right) of the fragment.

Each time you replace a fragment from the `FragmentTransaction` you need to set the `setCustomAnimations`

**sample:**

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(inL, inR, outL, outR);
    transaction.replace(layout, fragment, tag);
    transaction.commit();
```

where `inL` and `inR` are entering animation and `outL` and `outR` are exiting animation animation

Comment: That solves the easier part of the question. Where the more difficult side is to detect what current fragment is being shown and to which fragment shall it transition to.

Comment: @Subby to detect the current fragment you can just check the TAG as you could see every time you replace a fragment you put a tag on it

Comment: "which fragment shall it transition to" that depends on your collection of fragments