# How to change activity of a screen with swipe? with some example

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity, swipe-gesture

I have 2 screens black with scroll View in it and then I would like to change these screen with a swipe. I am using Android Studio and want to have a simple example so that i could change all the screens from one to other using swipe view. I hope the best example from the all the best developers on opposite side.

Thanks.

Comment: Search for ViewPager, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts

Comment: Thanx Campiador this worked the best for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View Pager will be the best suited component. There are a lot of samples available in the net.