# Android FragmentViewPager in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm trying to implement a ViewPager into my fragment. Here is my Code:

Parent fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    return view;
}
```

Childfragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);

    return v;
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new ChildFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
}
```

So after a while of searching I found out, that I need to use

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager()
```

But nothing happens! With the child fragment is all right, this can be shown as a single fragment, but not in my view pager. 
Width and height is everywhere "match_parent". 
The viewPager is in a LinearLayout which is in a scrollView. Could be the scrollview the reason?
I don't have any ideas anymore. Can someone help? Thanks a lot! :)

EDIT:
I used this tut:
[How to implement a ViewPager with different Fragments / Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)

Comment: did you try getSupportFragmentManager() ? you getChildFragmentManager() for nester fragments , in this case getSupportFragmentManager() (if using suport library ) or getFragmentManager() should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to your scrollview