# HorizontalScrollView in View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

I have view pager with list of child views. Every child is horizontal view. When horizontal view is not active view pager not scroll to the next page. If horizontal view is active then It scrolls horizontally but in horizontal scroll view. I need to scroll to next page of view pager if the horizontal view is not active. So I don't know where to handle this action and how to do it.

Comment: `ScrollView has a Single child.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following is a complete example of how to implement a ViewPager with different fragment Types and different layout files.

Try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)