# ViewPager textview not images

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, textview

Could anyone please help me as I want to implement viewpager textview, instead of images, I have searched on google however I cant manage to find any tutorials or help.

I have looked android developer sample. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#views

This is something which I am looking for however I want to show two different views of textviews, instead of repeating the same textview when swiping the screen. The sample shows 5 views which are all repating the same textview, however I want to have two views which are two different textviews, e.g, textview1 and textview2.

Could you please advise however I am able to do this, or if their are any tutorials to help me to achieve this.

Comment: just put TextView instead of imageview in fragment xml and you are good to go.

Comment: Vulovic Vukasin the example from android developer already shows it in textview, however could you give me another example as this one is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different fragments and put different textview in each. I am providing the link of viewpager with different fragment.

[How to implement a ViewPager with different Fragments / Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)