# Android ViewPager - How to swipe to specific position?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager`  that use Fragments, i need to swipe with this `ViewPager` but in position = x and for some condition i need to jump from this position to next one, so do not display this specific position. what is the method to do this?

Comment: Here is a great answer: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int previousposition=viewPager.getCurrentItem();

viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (previousPosition > position) {
            // here you handle the left scroll
        } else {
            // and here you handle the right scroll
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

It helps you to move from one position to another.

Comment: how i can specify the position?? i mean if the user scroll right i make position=position +2; and left position=position-2 ; but how i can get if he swipe left or right

Comment: I post another solution according to your requirement plz check it .