# What is the best way to create a simple slideshow into an Android project?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-sliding

I am absolutly new in **Android** development and I am developing my first app.

I have to create something like a **slideshow** that show an image, when the user moove to the right (with the finger on the screen, what's the correct name in Android jargon?) show the next immage, when it moove to the left the previous one is shown.

I have found this example, I have to implement something like the result shown in the attached video: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/

But my doutbs are:

In the prvious tutorial it use 2 external library that have to be added to the project:

- **Universal Image Loader for Android:** for asynchronous image loading.
- **ViewPagerIndicator:** library to bring circle indicator with ViewPager.

Is it a good solution? Or can I obtain the same behavior without using external library but only stuff provided by the **Android SDK**?

I think that the result of the previous tutorial is what I need for my project but I prefer don't use external library and adhere as much as possible to the standard of Android development.

Can you give me some suggestion about the right way to implement this feature?

Comment: *Is it a good solution?* primarily opinion-based ... *Or can I obtain the same behavior without using external library but only stuff provided by the Android SDK?* yes, by rewriting the libraries code *Can you give me some suggestion about the right way to implement this feature?* too broad

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts

Comment: is it solved or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create slideshow using viewFlipper 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way is viewpager with Universal Image Loader for Android

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using viewpager i suggest you to use [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow)

```
<it.moondroid.coverflow.components.ui.containers.FeatureCoverFlow
        android:id="@+id/coverflow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        coverflow:coverHeight="@dimen/cover_height"
        coverflow:coverWidth="@dimen/cover_width"
        coverflow:maxScaleFactor="1.5"
        coverflow:reflectionGap="0px"
        coverflow:rotationThreshold="0.5"
        coverflow:scalingThreshold="0.5"
        coverflow:spacing="0.6" />
```