# Use multiple layout files for one activity, is it a good way to go ? And how to slide layout files?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm making my first app but I'm not sure to the method I use. I'll try to be clear:

I have three layout files: `activity_main.xml` for my first screen, `menu.xml` for the menu, and the last `content.xml` for show the content  the people needs.

The first (`activity_main.xml`) has 2 boutons: **training**, **lessons**.

When clicking on one of them it's `menu.xml` which come with a list of button to access to the content. When the user make his choice it's `content.xml` appears.

`content.xml` is a long LinearLayout with a lot of elements, and I make visible the elements compared at the choice to the user.

I thought make 3 layout files was simple for manage the content I have to show (menu show different buttons if the user choose **lessons** or **training** and `content.xml` can show a lot of different elements) but now I'm trying to make my layout files sliding on the screen when they are call but I don't know how to do, all the animation I try to do give me:

> Null pointer Exception.

So I look on the internet and I see than people who make multiple layout files if for different API level and not just for make "new page". So I would like to know your view. Is it a good way to make different layout files like this ?

And if it's not a so bad idea, do you know how I can resolve my problem to slide them ? ( I tried to create object from the layout, to slide the layout file directly, but nothing works)

Answer (score 1):

Viewpager can be used for multiple screen that can be slide one after another.

[Exapmle and Answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)

Answer (score 0):

Viewpager will be helpfull for this follow the link for example

https://dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using