# Want to add explode transition effect in an intro screen

Tags: android, android-transitions

I am creating an intro screen which contain number of slides but not able to add explode transition effect in last screen. See the below link example:

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/244395/screenshots/2525702/silvva_-android-gif.gif

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Comment: can you tried for this screen ?

Comment: @SandeepPatel Yes able to create a simple screen but how to add similar effect in last screen

Comment: follow the @NileshRathod link

Comment: @SandeepPatel I know about that link my concept is differ from that.Open my link it is not a simple intro screen it also contains some animation.

Comment: u want to study about a gesture in android not sure but it's helpful for u

Comment: I'm using a viewPager with transition efects.

Comment: @Antonio If you have solution then please share

Comment: @Neha hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **ViewPager** wich loads differents fragments (every fragment contains what you want to display, like your exemple)

Here a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413437/9388338

When you finally can display differents fragments in your viewPager then you can add a custom animation to you viewPager.

Like this: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

It could be what you want.