# Show Row Per Row While Scrolling Listview -- Android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, row

I have a listview with rows as big as the device screen and I want to show row per row while sliding, I don't want to show parts of rows when doing so, is there any way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListViews are not made for this kind of use case. [ViewPagers](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) are, but they scroll horizontally. It's possible to make it scroll vertically (see [Android: Vertical ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager)), which should be what you're looking for.

The problem with adjusting the size of each ListView item to fill the screen is that match_parent simply doesn't work. You would need to calculate the exact size you need (screen height minus action bar and other views that are not part of the ListView). It's probably possible, but not worth the trouble.

Comment: .. I see, Thank you @Vlad, i shall look into that.

Comment: .. Can i use a row layout for The View Pager same as ListView ?