# How to make vertical lockable scrollview in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

Now am using horizontal lockable scroll view.
(i.e) am just scrolling the linear layout horizontally when ever the next button and back button is clicked respectively.so I used one Lockablescrollview class extends Horizontalscrollview to perform the linear layout to move horizontally.

Now I want that to scroll it on vertically.
Need help thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewPager with negative page margin to partly show the next and the previous pages and ViewPager.PageTransformer to give the illusion of a Vertical ViewPager. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619/2080305)