# How to create vertical multi viewpager in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I see several implementations for horizontal multi view viewpager but none for vertical multi view viewpager.

I was able to successfully create vertical viewpager and add a vertical transformer. I want to show multiple vertical pages using vertical viewpager. I tried setting page width and the page is showing next to current page horizontally. Any way to show it vertically ?

I also set

```
    setClipToChildren(false); 

    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
return 0.5f;
```

}

```
    <PagerDemo.VerticalViewPager     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="40px"
android:paddingRight="40px" />

    namespace PagerDemo
        {
           public class VerticalViewPager: Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager 
             {
    public VerticalViewPager (Context context):base(context) {

        Init ();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, IAttributeSet attr):base(context, attr) {

        Init();
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) {

        e.SetLocation (e.GetY (), e.GetX ());
        return base.OnTouchEvent (e);
    }

    private void Init()  {

        SetPageTransformer (true, new VeriticalPageTransformer());
        OverScrollMode = Android.Views.OverScrollMode.Never;
    }
```

}

}

Comment: heres what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager

Comment: I did that already. I need to show multiple pages vertically at the same time.

Comment: @Abhilash : what width & height you have defined for fragment pager ?

Comment: I updated my question with layout file and vertical viewpager implementation.