# Load HTML files on scroll in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app in which I have 20 HTML pages. I want to load all HTML pages on the fly when a scroll event happens.

For example, consider that I have a list view of list1, list2, list3, ...listn. When the user clicks on, say, list1, the corresponding HTML page should open, and when the user scrolls up, the next HTML page should get opened in the same layout or view.

Comment: @Abhishek : Since I am new to Android, I did not try any work around yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use vertical view pager that scrolls up next html page in sameview.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619/3513479)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I hope the link given should work for me. I have doubt: are we loading all the html files at once and then we  are navigating? or are we loading one page at a time when we scroll down or up?

Comment: you can load one page at a time and when you scroll view pager take next position and load second page on it and so on...