# Android RecyclerView with Fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, fragmentpageradapter

I have a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter. My customer wants me to switch from ViewPager to list; a vertical list with all the fragments.

There can be a lot of fragments, so adding them all in a ScrollView is out of the question.

Can I somehow do this while still using a FragmentPagerAdapter? Adding fragments to, for example, the views in a recyclerview is not a good idea, I suppose?

What might be a good solution? I'm afraid I will have to stop using fragments for this altogether, but there is a lot of controller code in these fragments.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619/2413303

Comment: But that will show screen-size pages. ViewPager needs to know the size of the page before it is rendered I think, if I override getPageWidth(int position) in the adapter, I need to know the size before redering, which I don't know. The pages have different heights and I don't want gaps in between: it should look like a list.

Comment: Ah. Well that's a shame, because that sounds like a RecyclerView thing.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use any fragments on any recycling views like list view, recycler view etc.   Fragments are attached to its container, in recycler view container will be changed frequently, as it is getting recycled. It will trouble later.

Better you can change the view pager to vertical scrolling view pager.
You can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager) to make it vertical scrolling.

Comment: I agree with the RecyclerView thing here, but unfortunately none of those solutions seem adequate enough for Frank. The solution would require more than just switching the orientation of ViewPager because of the varying heights of the fragments.

Comment: Jep, I'll accept this as an answer, I will have to rebuild the whole structure, get rid of the fragments and use a recyclerview instead.