# ScrollView with Items of ScreenSize

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, subviews

i need a vertical ScrollView which contains 4 Buttons.
Each Button should be of the Size of the Phone.

Something like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="First Content."
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Second Content."
        android:textSize="50dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I tried a lot of options but dont get how to manage this.

Comment: I guess you need something like this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager

Comment: That seems to be it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do a dynamic layout

keep a layout in your xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnr_layout_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

and then in your activity/fragment java file

```
LinearLayout lnLayoutContainer=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lnr_layout_container);
```

Calculate height of your device

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Now Inflate and add Buttons to your layout container

```
     for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
               {

                Button btnView= new Button(context);
                <set your button properties and listener here>

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
                layoutParams.weight = 1;
                btnView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                lnLayoutContainer.addView(txtViewChar);
                }
```