# Creating a recycler view with certain requirements.

Tags: android, listview, custom-controls, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create a specific type of recycler view with following requirements:

1) RecyclerView that would show one item per screen (**1 row will take the size of screen**).

2) When I scroll the recyclerview it should stop scrolling as soon as the next item is visible. (**Captures the whole screen**).

Please tell me if that is possible or not.

Comment: OfCourse this is possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619/4395530 . 
You can use viewpager instead.
Yes, you can implement it using recyclerview but it will be more complex than implementing it with viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use RecyclerView?
Probably you can do that with View Pager.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619

Comment: That could be a solution but I want a Gmail like row swipe implementation also . On swiping left or right on the row would delete the row and scroll to next item.

Comment: I have a solution. But, I have no confidence. 1. Create CoordnaitorLayout as Page in ViewPager.  2. Your contents put to CoordinatorLayout. 3. Set SwipeDissmissBehavior to your contents View.