# Android: Multi-Directional view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, vertical-scrolling

I need to implement the following app design:

- User can swipe 'columns' left and and right (Horizontal Page Viewer style)
- In each 'column', the user can swipe up and down (Vertical Page Viewer style)

On iOS, UIPageViewController can be vertical or horizontal. I implemented the design as follow: At the top, there is one horizontal page view controller where every view returned by this controller is managed by a vertical page view controller. Everything worked great.

However **on Android, there is no vertical view pager** so I followed the suggestion in [vertical-view-pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager) however I am faced with this problem:
If a column contain pages P1 and P2, then I can only swip left if P1 is shown at top and I can swipe right only if P2 is shown at bottom. I want to swipe left/right from any page.

I did browse for other implementations of vertical/directional view pagers but most implementations are obsolete like [directional-view-pager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) 
My question: do you know of any solid (latest and greatest) implementation of a vertical View Pager on android? 
Thanks
Max