# RecyclerView with page scrolling (Vertical ViewPager)

Tags: android-recyclerview, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I want to open a different row on scrolling `RecyclerView` vertically and hide previous row completely. Similar to `ViewPager` but vertically. I have tried the library [VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager), but it is just a vertical `RecyclerView`.

Please suggest me.

Comment: do you want to use a recycleview or view pager ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Vertical ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager)

Comment: Here's an answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18657771/3145960

Comment: Recyclerview or anything that will fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Didn't find solution. Will have to use external [library](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager)