# Only one complete view(row) in display in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling

I have a recycler view in which I have inflated a layout containing some textviews and an imageview. Everything works as expected but I am facing a little problem while scrolling.

I want a behaviour where if user scrolls up or down the complete row which is currently in display should move and the new row comes is displayed. Right now when I am scrolling both the rows are partially visible.

How to achieve such behaviour in Recyclerview in android?

I am attaching a screenshot of my app if you guys want I can also post my code.[image]

Comment: I would use `ViewPager` for what you want but it works horizontally. Check out this question for more details http://stackoverflow.com/q/13477820/2445241

Comment: I am familier with Viewpagers but I want this in vertical scrolling

Comment: The link I gave you has some vertical view pagers / recycler views that do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try out this library by kaelaela:

https://github.com/kaelaela/VerticalViewPager

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use a library.