# Vertical ScrollView inside a Vertical ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have implemented `Vertical ViewPager` from this: [Android: Vertical ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager/22797619#22797619)

I have a fragments which contains `ScrollView` inside. What I want to do is to switch the pages only when the `ScrollView inside has reached at the end`. When ScrollView is at the end, further scrolling should switch the pages in ViewPager.

Comment: Nice! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Two Scrolling not working  properly together in same direction.

Comment: use nested scrollview, i dnt prefer it. but will help

Comment: u should to extend scrollview class and create your own onTouch logic

Comment: did you got the solution? facing same issue