# Unable to implement Vertical CircleIndicator in Vertical View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, vertical-alignment, geometry, indicator

I need to implement vertical view pager with vertical circle indicator in my activity.

Vertical View pager is working fine, I have problem with Vertical circle indicator.

[I have made custom class for view pager from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager/18657771#18657771)

and custom class for circle indicator , but no luck

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after digging for 4 5 hours 
its just one line i was missed ..

```
 indicator.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Following is my activity class

```
final VerticalViewPager viewpager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_default);
        CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator_default);
        viewpager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter(ViewProfileActivity.this,listImgUrls));
        viewpager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                viewpager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
        indicator.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        indicator.setViewPager(viewpager);
```