# ViewPager shows Textviews from first fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin

Hey I am trying to implement a vertical viewpager and been  been successful so far. But when I scroll down to get to my second fragment which is blank with an orange background the textviews from my inital fragment are shown.

**Inital View**

[image: Pic 1]

**After Scrolling**

[image: Pic2]

I implemented the vertical pager from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager) (the first one with 180 upvotes)

My project is also on [github](https://github.com/Gnadi/Alfred.git)

If you got any questions feel free to ask in the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Provide to first fragment a colored background(can be transparent also or white) it should resolve it.
You can use for transparent the following: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried to set the background of my activity_main with the textviews and the fragment_main with the text views in it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your project in GitHub, your `TextViews` are being added to the `R.id.innerLay` `LinearLayout`, which is in your Activity, but they're are not in any of the fragments which are part of the `R.id.pager` `ViewPager`. You need to move the `TextViews` to the `R.layout.fragment_main` which will prevent them from showing in `R.layout.fragment_second`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I made the changes but now I got every text view twice I think and the problem is still here. I pushed my changes on my github repo

Comment: Move the  `val inLay = findViewById<View>(R.id.innerLay) as LinearLayout for (x in 0..9) { inLay.addView(getView(x)) }` and `getView()` method from your Activity to the fragment and see if it works.

Comment: no did not work this cannot be the problem. With this code I initialize my horizontal view so I dont think that the problem is there