# How do I create a vertical scrolling ViewPager with a horizontal TabLayout as header?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design

I want to create a `ViewPager` which is vertical scrolling with a `CardView` as its items. It will be linked to a `TabLayout` as its header. The `TabLayout` will change the inner `ViewPager`. It will be like the image below.

[image: Representative image]

The list of seasons will be the `TabLayout` and the episodes in that season will be the `ViewPager`.

Comment: please **follow** this link [android-vertical-viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager)

Comment: @NileshRathod It's not just about the making vertical ViewPager. I have already done that. It's about making the whole thing.