# How to create Vertical swipe screens in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gesture, android-swipe

I am trying to Create a Two Fragments and add a vertical swiping effect to that.Actually, I got few answers during searching.But I am still confusing about vertical swiping creation.Can anyone suggest how to start or give some references?I am just a Beginner in android so every small help will be very useful.

Comment: when you call anyother fragment then it goes upword?

Comment: I think [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager) is what you need .

Comment: @Waleed Asim yeah ,like swiping the screens in up/down ward direction

Comment: @ADM yeah i need like this.