# ViewPager in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have created a android app UI in which I have added a image view in recycler view and now I want is that when user swipes over the image , the comments of images should seen. plz help me to do it either by using viewpager or anything else.

Comment: Check this [Vertical RecyclerView with Horizontal ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308629/implement-viewpager-inside-vertical-viewpager/52310286#52310286)

Comment: thanks bro for your help @NileshRathod

Comment: Could explain it in detail.. I'm assuming you want to open new activity for comments on swipe at every image in recyclerview. Right?

Comment: no I don't want to open a new activity @paragpawar. I only want is that whenever user swipes on image , user should able to see comments in that activity only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Gesture detector classes to detect swipe event and  inflate view of your image comments. 
Here is the link for reference:

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector

Here is the example for the implementation.

https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/android-swipe-gestures-tutorial/

Also, kindly please share your base code for better help.