# Horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview unable to load data properly

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to implement horizontal recycler view inside a vertical recycler view and So that I scroll through the horizontal items two at a time. Data is coming from `api`. But the horizontal recycler view is unable to load data properly and app crashes on scroll. I have researched throughout the stack for solution, but still I could not get one. Following is my Code:

OuterRecyclerView Adapter(Verticle):

```
public class CategoryBannerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryBannerAdapter.CategoryBannerViewHolder> {
    private final RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool;
    Context context;
    List<Datum> bannerList;
    ICartDelegate listener;

    private static final String TAG = "CategoryBannerAdapter";

    public  CategoryBannerAdapter(Context context, List<Datum> bannerList, ICartDelegate listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bannerList = bannerList;
        this.listener = listener;
        viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryBannerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_banner_cell, null, false);

        return new CategoryBannerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryBannerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Datum datum = bannerList.get(position);
        LinearLayout a = null;

        Picasso.get().load(datum.getBanner().getBannerImg()).placeholder(R.drawable.hapdel_logo_small).fit().into(holder.banner_img);
        holder.banner_title_text.setText(datum.getBanner().getTitle());
        holder.view_more_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, OpenProductActivity.class);
                com.utility.hapdel.Model.CategoryModel.ParentCategoryModel.Datum datum1 = new com.utility.hapdel.Model.CategoryModel.ParentCategoryModel.Datum();
                datum1.setId(datum.getBanner().getCategoryId());
                intent.putExtra("category", new Gson().toJson(datum1));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.product_title.setText(datum.getBanner().getTitle());

        holder.product_recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        if(datum.getItems()!=null && datum.getItems().size()>=0){
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: mitems size "+datum.getBanner().getTitle()+"  "+ datum.getItems().size());
            int indiator_size = (int) Math.ceil((Double.valueOf(datum.getItems().size()))/ 2);



            holder.productsAdapter.updateItems(datum.getItems());
            holder.productsAdapter.setRowIndex(position);

            //adding circle indicator to recyclerview
            holder.circleIndicator.setItemCount(indiator_size);
            holder.circleIndicator.setCurrentPosition(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bannerList.size();
    }

    public void updateItems(List<Datum> data) {
        if(data !=null){
            bannerList = data;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class CategoryBannerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
        private ProductsAdapter productsAdapter;
        private RecyclerView product_recycler_view;
        private TextView banner_title_text;
        private ImageView banner_img;
        private RelativeLayout root_layout;
        private TextView view_more_btn;
        private TextView product_title;
        private AnyViewIndicator circleIndicator;
        private Context mContext;

        public CategoryBannerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            banner_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.banner_img);
            root_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
            product_recycler_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_recycler_view);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen._15sdp),0,context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen._10sdp));
            root_layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            banner_title_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.banner_title_text);
            view_more_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_more_btn);
            product_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
            circleIndicator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.banner_indicator1);

       gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            product_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(context, new ArrayList<Product>(), listener);
            product_recycler_view.setAdapter(productsAdapter);

        }
    }
}
```

ParentRecyclerView XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/banner_title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp"
            android:theme="@style/banner_title" />

        <View
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/faded_line"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_12sdp"></View>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/banner_card"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/banner_img"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="#10000000" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/banner_logo"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/logo"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/banner_logo_txt"
                    style="@style/banner_logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/banner_logo"
                    android:text="hapdel"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryGreen"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="Best Price Guaranteed"
                    android:theme="@style/banner_offer"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/banner_btn"
                    android:text="GRAB"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/_100sdp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <View
                    android:id ="@+id/empty_view"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryGreen"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



        <HorizontalScrollView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:scrollbars="none"

            android:id="@+id/title_horizontalScrollView"

            android:layout_margin="1dp"

            android:fillViewport="false">



            <LinearLayout

                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                >

                <GridView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:id="@+id/listview"

                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"></GridView>



            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>


        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/product_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <com.kingfisher.easyviewindicator.AnyViewIndicator
            android:id="@+id/banner_indicator1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:avi_animation_enable="false"
            app:avi_drawable="@drawable/blue_radius"
            app:avi_drawable_unselected="@drawable/gray_radius"
            app:avi_height="10dp"
            app:avi_margin="10dp"
            app:avi_orientation="horizontal"
            app:avi_width="10dp"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_more_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
            android:text="View More"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Data from Api:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "msg": 5,
    "data": [
        {
            "banner": {
                "title": "Instant Yummy Maggie",
                "banner_img": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/c65e1450352d2f07c7ef1f6451f31f3c.jpg",
                "category_id": "70",
                "product_category_id": "80"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "pid": "96",
                    "seller_id": "2",
                    "store_name": "Fresh Menu",
                    "image": "353ac8c1b39f076c335a3abf902a96a8.jpg",
                    "type": "product",
                    "category_id": "80",
                    "product_name": "Insant Noodles",
                    "per": "6",
                    "unit": "g",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "141.00-229.00",
                    "stocks": "499",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "97",
                    "seller_id": "2",
                    "store_name": "Fresh Menu",
                    "image": "e8e37e93a78fe3b399ed22d740f36e26.jpg",
                    "type": "product",
                    "category_id": "80",
                    "product_name": "Instant noodles yummy",
                    "per": "7",
                    "unit": "g",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "310.00-632.00",
                    "stocks": "499",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "banner": {
                "title": "Chocolates",
                "banner_img": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/f10ef33b8a6228f0c60e526ebbcbbcce.jpg",
                "category_id": "72",
                "product_category_id": "86"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "pid": "110",
                    "seller_id": "2",
                    "store_name": "Fresh Menu",
                    "image": "b6f28f0164a1f1fdd243bdfe13df19aa.png",
                    "type": "product",
                    "category_id": "86",
                    "product_name": "Dairy milk chocolate",
                    "per": "8",
                    "unit": "g",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "102.00-347.00",
                    "stocks": "499",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "111",
                    "seller_id": "2",
                    "store_name": "Fresh Menu",
                    "image": "a1044f6b7892564e33e72df6a6d08fed.jpg",
                    "type": "product",
                    "category_id": "86",
                    "product_name": "5 star",
                    "per": "6",
                    "unit": "g",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "455.00-934.00",
                    "stocks": "496",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "112",
                    "seller_id": "2",
                    "store_name": "Fresh Menu",
                    "image": "587b990f756057946ca5ad4c1c94f5b3.jpg",
                    "type": "product",
                    "category_id": "86",
                    "product_name": "Kitkat",
                    "per": "7",
                    "unit": "g",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "870.00-979.00",
                    "stocks": "500",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "banner": {
                "title": "Caps Ballons",
                "banner_img": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/a36bd4894b7945b3c4e0e45440c43f47.jpg",
                "category_id": "134",
                "product_category_id": "138"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "pid": "189",
                    "seller_id": "2",
                    "store_name": "Fresh Menu",
                    "image": "c8a7ff1cbedf91e705ca869c9273f70a.jpg",
                    "type": "product",
                    "category_id": "138",
                    "product_name": "Party Caps",
                    "per": "6",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "185.00-479.00",
                    "stocks": "500",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "190",
                    "seller_id": "2",
                    "store_name": "Fresh Menu",
                    "image": "7b53910622fac5ba343ed6f995961469.jpg",
                    "type": "product",
                    "category_id": "138",
                    "product_name": "Party Ballons",
                    "per": "6",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "613.00-739.00",
                    "stocks": "500",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "191",
                    "seller_id": "2",
                    "store_name": "Fresh Menu",
                    "image": "3f45e1be5b986398666306c2ed555bab.jpg",
                    "type": "product",
                    "category_id": "138",
                    "product_name": "Party Candels",
                    "per": "6",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "168.00-546.00",
                    "stocks": "500",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "banner": {
                "title": "Kitchen Cleaning",
                "banner_img": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/c3c47befb86a95f90b34e85d67339558.jpg",
                "category_id": "195",
                "product_category_id": "197"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "pid": "269",
                    "seller_id": "55",
                    "store_name": "Happy Store",
                    "image": "9bebd507b222497ca94ace717683f415.jpg",
                    "type": "service",
                    "category_id": "197",
                    "product_name": "Kitchen Cleaner with Chimney",
                    "per": "3",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "52.00-411.00",
                    "stocks": "0",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "270",
                    "seller_id": "55",
                    "store_name": "Happy Store",
                    "image": "684e9d9254109d096a24f1fa49ff8e2f.jpg",
                    "type": "service",
                    "category_id": "197",
                    "product_name": "Kitchen Cleaning Without Chimney ",
                    "per": "4",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "205.00-634.00",
                    "stocks": "0",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "272",
                    "seller_id": "55",
                    "store_name": "Happy Store",
                    "image": "7579fb3d47f8b4fa67c4e5600cbe2bc6.jpg",
                    "type": "service",
                    "category_id": "197",
                    "product_name": "Kitchen Trolly and Shelf Cleaning",
                    "per": "3",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "300.00-913.00",
                    "stocks": "0",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "273",
                    "seller_id": "55",
                    "store_name": "Happy Store",
                    "image": "3caeab50226053e1392f951348f837cc.jpg",
                    "type": "service",
                    "category_id": "197",
                    "product_name": "Kitchen deep Cleaning",
                    "per": "7",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "236.00-937.00",
                    "stocks": "0",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "banner": {
                "title": "AC Service",
                "banner_img": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/3cc9c9053a2d5a8907eb88ecbba9967c.jpg",
                "category_id": "241",
                "product_category_id": "249"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "pid": "288",
                    "seller_id": "55",
                    "store_name": "Happy Store",
                    "image": "bf009db960495c3b431e305a80167726.jpg",
                    "type": "service",
                    "category_id": "249",
                    "product_name": "Window AC",
                    "per": "7",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "334.00-862.00",
                    "stocks": "0",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                },
                {
                    "pid": "289",
                    "seller_id": "55",
                    "store_name": "Happy Store",
                    "image": "2ccf78dee8ea40d32881491d60535b49.jpg",
                    "type": "service",
                    "category_id": "249",
                    "product_name": "Split AC",
                    "per": "7",
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "status": "y",
                    "brand": null,
                    "price": "626.00-830.00",
                    "stocks": "0",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "base_url": "https://hapdel.com/assets/uploads/"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310286/7666442

Comment: There should be something in the log from the crash, please show that in the question, to help answer it.

Comment: @Andrew Log that comes when i scroll horizontally:     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 2(offset:2).state:3 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{3c22aeb VFED..... ........ 0,0-1008,780 #7f0a027f app:id/product_recycler_view}, adapter:com.utility.hapdel.Adapter.ProductsAdapter@f821048, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@b070ee1, context:com.utility.hapdel.Activity.HomeActivity@6e6107d

Comment: @NileshRathod But I need inner items gridwise, so that 2  items get scrolled simulataneously when scrolled horzontaly

Comment: Looks a very similar error to a crash I had https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145941830