# Vertical ViewPager with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to show 3 fragments below each other. So far I've used many solutions such as [YViewPager](https://github.com/youngkaaa/YViewPagerDemo) and answers such as [Android: Vertical ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager/16920135). The main problem with them is non of them working the way I want. I need to show a first fragment and below that, some part of the second one, and when user scrolled to next one, showing second fragment and some part of third one.
The `YViewPager` was great until I added these lines to show some part of second fragment:

```
viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
viewPager.setPadding(0,0,0,500);
```

After that, it became like this: [image]

With that white space that came out of nowhere.
And as for other libraries and hacks which told me to swap motion event:

```
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent event) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (event.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (event.getX() / width) * height;

    event.setLocation(newX, newY);
    return event;
}
```

And also rewrite the `PageTransformer`.
Here everything was good until I wanted to go from second fragment to the first one. It wanted to set the alpha to 0 to begin the transformation but this creates some sudden disappearance for the third fragment like this:

[image]

Well, here is my question:

Is there anyway to achieve this kind of view without these problems?
Do you suggest some other approaches?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve the described behavior much easier using RecyclerView and SnapHelper. Here is a link where you can find some explanation with some sources https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap