# How to slide only half Fragment while using vertical ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I was looking for **vertical viewpager** then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797619/7858689)
it's working fine, but now I need to slide only **half** of the fragment.

I did this before, using **horizontal viewpager** with below solution

> Override the getPageWidth method of PagerAdapter and make it return 0.5f;

but because I'm using **vertical viewpager** instead of **horizontal viewpager**, and FragmentPagerAdapter does not have any override method to return **height**

Is there any possible solution to do it?
[image: some thing I'm trying to do]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace `VerticalPageTransformer` class with this source

```
private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) {
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) {
            view.setAlpha(1);
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
            float yPosition = position * (float)(view.getHeight() / 2.5);
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else {
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}
```

it works perfectly ;)