# ImageView in HorizontalScrollView android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, horizontal-scrolling

I want to make a HorizontalScrollView including multiple ImageViews in android studio, It's easy, but I want it to show only single ImageView with width=match_parent on my screen, something like what you can see on Instagram posts, images are side by side, but you can see one image only, and you can scroll to next or previous images, please help me...

Comment: why not use a **RecyclerView** with horizontal scrolling?

Comment: I don't know how it works, I'm beginner in development for android, can you write the code for me and guide me how to use it?

Comment: please follow this [tutorial](https://demonuts.com/android-horizontal-recyclerview/)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution - is to use vertical View Pager. Here you can see simple example and links to already implemented ones on GitHub - [Android: Vertical ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477820/android-vertical-viewpager)